# WebStorm, is it possible to use GitHub markdown theme in preview while using overall dark theme?

Tags: webstorm

Tried to follow this manual, but it doesn't work: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/markdown.html#css

[image]

Is it possible at all? Did somebody succeed in this task?

Comment: Do you want to use GitHub light theme in your WebStorm dark theme? If so, then you can fill the "Add CSS rules" box: `body {
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #424242;
  font-family: "Open Sans", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

1. Download one of the markdown css files from https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/.
2. In the Markdown prefs, set the custom css to point to that file (URLs don't work).
3. Paste this into the "Add CSS rules:" field:

```css
.markdown-body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 45px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .markdown-body {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

4. At the top of your markdown file, insert this (the blank line is important):

```markdown
<div class="markdown-body">
```

5. At the bottom of your markdown file, insert this:

```markdown
</div>
```

That's it!